# AS3 How to delete an object for good?

Tags: actionscript-3

I create a new Shape, make a listener that starts a function when an object hits the shape, the function clears graphics of the shape, removes listener and deletes the child. But it looks like it leaves some ghost that still triggers when my object comes to it's place. I'm not sure why it happens, I thought clear+remove should make it impossible to hitTest. But somehow children still pile over one another and the last created one triggers the function. So if you understand, please give me a hint, if not please tell me in general **what is a way to delete a created Shape for good, so it didn't count existing?**

A bit of details. Hitting the shape must start a function that deletes it and creates a new shape of the same name that has a different function that does the same etc. so the current function must be the one I called for, not the last one, whose listener I deleted. Making new shape each time may overload memory, besides I do clean up every time. Did I forget anything?

```
fun0(){
  var bob:Shape = new Shape();
  addChild(bob);
  bob...drawRect...
  addEventListener(...,fun1)
  function fun1(){ if(hitTest...){
  bob...clear();
  removeChild(bob);
  removeEventListener(...,fun1)
  fun2();
  } 
 }


fun2(){
  var bob:Shape = new Shape();
  addChild(bob);
  bob...drawRect...
  addEventListener(...,fun3)
  function fun1(){ if(hitTest...){
  bob...clear();
  removeChild(bob);
  removeEventListener(...,fun3)
  fun0();
  } 
}
```

etc., it only sees fun3 after I once trigger it even though I deleted the listener. Again, I do move object away, it doesn't hitTest anymore, then clear+remove. If you don't understand or cannot help, please don't flame, just ignore this, I need help, not the info that I'm not as smart as you are. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first of dont declare functions inside of functions. then use weak reference for event listners.

```
// params: eventName, listener, capturePhase, priority, useWeakReference
someObj.addEventListener("eventName",myFunct,false,0,true);
```

you musst get rid of any references to the object, then set it to null

```
removeChild(bob); 
bob= null;
```

after that GC will collect it!

edit:

if you keep doing the hitTest, like on enterFrame for example. check if the object is on the stage, by checking its .stage property.

```
if(bob.stage)
  {
    if(hitTest ...){};
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work... Null does something weird to the code and when I go back to previous function it says error, "hitTestObject parameter shouldn't be null". Also, you mean I shouldn't call for a function inside a function? I thought it's a usual thing, how else do I trigger another function?

Comment: No, i said you shouldnt declare a function inside of another, obviously you call them. If you keep hitTesting for that object you musst determen if it exists first, i'll update answer

Comment: Nope, it wont. It made a bit of sense about functions, if I put function starter inside another fun. it's like the endless "inception" of functions. But checking if bob.stage doesn't help. And I do create this shape, it should find it even without checking. Shape nulling causes error... Thanks for trying to help though, these were good guesses.

Comment: thats only what i can tell from your pseudo code. But are still things you will have to do and not guesses. You will have to show real code to propperly help! edit your question und put the actual code in